# Selenium cant find the xpath element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I am making a script to generate icloud mails and in the apple wbesite there is a button that selenium cant find and this error is displayed in the console:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/aside/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/section[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/button"}

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(r'https://appleid.apple.com/sign-in?returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fappleid.apple.com%2Faccount%2Fmanage%2Fsection%2Fprivacy&appId=93')
print("login your icloud account and press keep me singed in")
login = input("Press enter when you have logged in")

#enter the email part 
browser.find_element("xpath", '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/main/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/button/div/div[1]/div').click()
time.sleep(5)


#press the add email button(doesnt work)
create= browser.find_element("xpath", '/html/body/aside/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/section[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/button')
create.click()
```

so the last part is the part that doesnt work, where it tries to press the add email button but it displays the error shown above, ive tried selecting other elements and nothing seems to work. Would appriciate some help:)

This image is the button that I was trying to click with selenium.

[image]

I tried to click the button ut the error shows up whatever I do.

Comment: Try using something like this for the xpath: //button[@class='your_button_class']  Probably using //button will also work in your case if the button is only one.

Comment: @Marcosjuncascrypto, is the element that you are trying to click on is inside an Iframe element?

Comment: @AlexKaramfilov I used that expath and the same error displays '    create= browser.find_element("xpath",  "//button[@class='button button-icon-only button-rounded-rectangle']")
    create.click() '

Comment: @TalAngel I dont think the element is inside an iframe, this is the html code screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/NRpgNxd

Comment: Maybe I could try to find the element by another method thats not xpath and it will work right? Do you guys know any other way?

Comment: apparently I have done some research and it is a pseudo element do you guys know what to do for selenium to click on it?

Comment: //button[@class=‘button’] will find it

Comment: First, don't use long Xpath expressions, it's a bad idea. 2nd, show the HTML structure of the element you wish to click on.